# Rails cant add duplicate model to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails and am still figuring a lot of things out. I currently have two models in my database, one is `product` which has attributes such as `price, name and description`. I also have a model called `cart` which has a `has_many` relationship with products. I also set up the `belongs_to` relationship within the `product` model.

The problem I am facing is this: I want to be able to add many products to a cart, I have a function called `add_to_cart` which pushes a `product` to the array of products for that `cart` object. However I noticed that I cannot add duplicate items to the cart, this is something I want to be able to do. Is there any way to fix this so that I can add duplicates of the same item to a cart's array that stores them? Once again this may be a dumb question but I am still trying to figure out the labyrinth of rails :)

Comment: Make a join table. If it helps, think of an actual shelf. think of water bottles as a product.  When you add that to the cart you need to make it into multiple products, so something like a `line_item` which has the product id and cart id and a count allows you to add 3 water bottles. Your product table is the info on the product, the line item is the actual product going into the cart. A line item belongs to a cart and belong to a product in order to tie the 2 together and then there would just be a count of how many `line items` you add to the cart. this is just one way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you need a create one more table cart_item with the filed cart_id, product_id and product's require field and whenever you add product in cart a cart_item create by same product id .
Product  (id:integer,price:float,name:string,description:text)
Cart (id:integer,user_id:integer)
cart_item  (id:integer,cart_id:integer,product_id:integer)

cart has_many cart_items
product has_many cart_items